# How to ensure to update Docker image on AWS ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I use Docker Hub to store a private Docker image, the repository has a webhook that once the image is updated it calls a service I built to:

- update the ECS task definition
- update the ECS service
- deregister the old ECS task definition

The service is running accordingly. After it runs ECS creates a new task with the new task definition, stops the task with the old task definition and the service come back with the new definition.

The point is that the Docker Image is not updated, once the service starts in the new task definition it remains with the old image.

Am I doing something wrong? How o ensure the docker image is updated?

Comment: do you use unique tags or sthg like `latest`?

Comment: @ZeissS I use latest.
My definition in the ECS Task is user/image:latest

Comment: I would recommend using a version tag. I guess the ECS agent only does the equivalent of `docker run`. The docker daemon only pulls images, if explicitly asked (`docker pull`) or he doesn't know the image.

Comment: i have a ticket opened for this situation on amazon support. They said ecs agent tell docker to do a pull. And asked me to provide a ecs agent logs for this situation, but i changed my workflow a bit right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After analysing the AWS ECS logs I found out that the problem was in the ECS Docker authentication.

To solve that I've added the following data to the file /etc/ecs/ecs.config

```
ECS_CLUSTER=default
ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_TYPE=dockercfg
ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_DATA={"https://index.docker.io/v1/":{"auth":"YOUR_DOCKER_HUB_AUTH","email":"YOUR_DOCKER_HUB_EMAIL"}}
```

Just replace the **YOUR_DOCKER_HUB_AUTH** and **YOUR_DOCKER_HUB_EMAIL** by your own information and it shall work properly.

To find this information you can execute `docker login` on your own computer and then look for the data in the file ~/.docker/config.json

For more information on the Private Registry Authentication topic please look at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/Welcome.html

Comment: You'll want to have the ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_DATA all on one line, rather than broken over several lines.

Comment: @SamuelK thanks, it was just a formatting issue, now it's fixed.